# Full Calender - Display all Days in an month on a single line

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar Plugin for my website (http://fullcalendar.io).

I want to display all days in an month in a single row like below:

```
 ******************** October *************************************** 

Room 101 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...................30
Room 102 : 1 2 3 ...............................30

 ******************** November *************************************** 

Room 101 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...................30
Room 102 : 1 2 3 ...............................30

 ******************** December *************************************** 

Room 101 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...................30
Room 102 : 1 2 3 ...............................30
```

How can I achieve this type of design?

Comment: Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Its Just an Single line of code that initializes the calender but i am unable to alter its height and width $('#calendar').fullCalendar();

Comment: @user3383301 were you able to achieve this? because this is what I want too